# Swift 4 new KVC

Tags: swift, swift-playground, kvc, swift4

I am trying to understand latest addition to Swift 4 - [better KVC](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md). Having this simple stuff in playground prints out nothing

```
class Foo {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Bar {

    var fooObject: Foo = Foo(name: "FooName")
    var keyPath = \Foo.name

    func output() {
        print(fooObject[keyPath: keyPath])
    }
}

let bar = Bar()
bar.output()
```

Although, it works if you make a small change and try to output this:

```
print(fooObject[keyPath: \Foo.name])
```

Can someone explain? Is it still buggy or am I just doing something stupid here? Thanks.

Comment: When changing "var keyPath = \Foo.name" to "let keyPath = \Foo.name" it works sometimes. Anyway doesn't seem like expected behavior.

Comment: Creating a Command Line Tool project with your code, Swift compiler stops with **`Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`** . Better send a bug report to bugs.swift.org .

Comment: Yes, I am getting a lot of 'Segmentation fault: 11' when trying to play with new KVC inside an actual project. Generally, this feature seems like 50% completed.

Comment: This is a compiler bug: [SR-5384](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5384)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to Xcode 9 beta 4, where it is fixed.